# Wind Chill C# final number needs more digits

Tags: c#, decimal, point

I have been trying to solve this formula about the wind chill, I get the result but I need more numbers after the decimal point. No matter what I tried it didn't work. Please help!

```
static void Main()
{
    double temp = 20;
    double wind = 7;

    double windChill = 35.74 + 0.6215 * temp + (0.4275 * temp - 35.75) * Math.Pow(wind, 0.16);

    Console.WriteLine("so wind_chill = {0}", Math.Round(windChill, 15));
}
```

In this I get final number `11.03490062551`, but I want `11.034900625509998`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You mean you want to get `11.034900625509991`?

Comment: Yes, I want more digits after the decimal point. I thought that `double` should be just fine, just in case I have tried with `decimal` as well. Either I am doing something wrong or I have no idea where the problem is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is not with `Math.Round`, `Math.Round` will actually give you `11.034900625509991` which I guess is what you want.

The problem is with `Console.WriteLine`, it is the method that is causing the precision loss (because internally, it calls `string.Format` which is actually causing the precision loss).

To fix it, use the [round-trip format specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx#RFormatString) like this:

```
Console.WriteLine("so wind_chill = {0:R}", Math.Round(windChill, 15));
```

Please note also that the value of `windChill` should be good enough for you. There is no need to call `Math.Round`.

Comment: For even more precision, use `decimal` (128-bit precision) instead of `double` (64-bit precission)